# Java naming convention for static mutator methods

Tags: java, methods, static, naming-conventions

For static methods in Java, the parameter cannot have the same name as a global static variable. Is there a convention for naming the parameter? ...just a curiosity.

private static volatile int metBetYetPetLetJet = 8675309;

public static void setMetBetYetPetLetJet (int metBetYetPetLetJet0) {
    metBetYetPetLetJet = metBetYetPetLetJet0;
}

Comment: Although the language allows the parameter to have the same name as the member -- as noted below -- that introduces a risk of confusion and error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give the same name and the rule applies the same as for the member variable's name.

Here: instead of `this` you have to refer the variable with the class name.

Answer (score 7):

The parameter absolutely *can* have the same name:

```
public class Foo {

    private static volatile int metBetYetPetLetJet = 8675309

    public static void setMetBetYetPetLetJet (int metBetYetPetLetJet) {
        Foo.metBetYetPetLetJet = metBetYetPetLetJet;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, I often just use `value` as the parameter name for a setter. That may be the influence of C# though :) Another option is `newValue`.